# What is the use of #pragma warning in C#?

Tags: c#, pragma

I just saw this code

```
#pragma warning disable 659, 660, 661
```

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28VS.80%29.aspx) is not helping much. What is the usage of this line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your link:

> `#pragma warning may be used to enable or disable certain warnings.`

If you know some code will throw a warning but you want to ignore it, you can then use this. This will prevent the message from being shown.

Answer (score 7):

In C# errors and warnings have numbers. `#pragma warning disable` allows you to suppress some warnings that the compiler might emit.